# JQuery Plugin - triggering internal functions by callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, closures, jquery-events

Skip to bottom for question

## JQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function( options ) {
    var options = $.extend({
        myOption: true,
        edit: function() {},
        done: function() {}
    }, options);

    options.edit.call(this);
    options.done.call(this);

    //plugin guts removed to prevent over complication

    return {
        edit: function(obj) {
            $(obj).closest('#myParent').find('#myInput').autosizeInput(); //plugin to autosize an input
        },
        done: function(obj) {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not('.not').each(function(i) {
                //do some things
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Bear in mind this is a cut down version of my plugin.**

## Called from page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myPlugin = $('.editable').myPlugin({
        edit: $(this).on('click', '.edit-td', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //do some page specific stuff
            myPlugin.edit( $(this) ); //call the edit returned function
        }),
        done: $(this).on('click', '.done-td', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //do some page specific stuff
            myPlugin.done( $(this) ); //call the done returned function
        });
    });
});
```

**This works great for the most part, however, what i really want is have functions called from inside my plugin every time a specific callback is triggered** - without the need to call from outside the plugin.

I have tried including delegated events in my plugin:

```
$(this).on('click', '.edit-td', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('#myParent').find('#myInput').autosizeInput();
});

$(this).on('click', '.done-td', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not('.not').each(function(i) {
        //do some things
    });
});
```

But when the `.edit-td` is triggered it propagates and triggers the `.done-td` event, if i put `e.stopPropagation()` in the `edit-td` function (because it has been delegated) `edit-td` stops firing completely.

And non-delegated method:

```
$(this).find('.done-td').click(function(e, this) {});
```

But I can't parse the returned object (`this`) to the internal function before the internal function has completed. (just comes up undefined or `missing formal parameter`).

## *Skip to here

**To avoid the question becoming to localised** -

> I need to have functions called from inside my
>   plugin every time a specific callback is triggered.
>   Without calling it using closures

Something like:

```
if( $.fn.myPlugin.callback().is('edit') ) {
    //fire function
}
```

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/

Comment: This was an interesting read and is actually what resolved my question. Please provide this as an answer and I will accept. Wibble.

Comment: when I read the question, I thought like you didn't got the idea about the callback, that's why I commented the link. if you got the answer you can close the question or keep it for better answers. I don't have much idea about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Ok I will close ty .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to return a function(s) like so:

```
return {
    enable: function(arg) {
        //do something
    },
    disable: function(arg) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

That way I can call it from inside my plugin by referencing itself like this:

```
    this.myPlugin().disable();
```